# Part of speech tagging in OpenNLP vs. StanfordNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, part-of-speech

I'm new to part of speech (pos) taging and I'm doing a pos tagging on a text document. I'm considering using either OpenNLP or StanfordNLP for this. For StanfordNLP I'm using a `MaxentTagger` and I use `english-left3words-distsim.tagger` to train it. In OpenNLP I'm using `POSModel` and train it using `en-pos-maxent.bin`. How these two taggers (`MaxentTagger` and `POSTagger`) and the training sets (`english-left3words-distsim.tagger` and `en-pos-maxent.bin`) are different and which one is usually giving a better result.

Answer (score 1):

Both POS taggers are based on Maximum Entropy machine learning. They differ in the parameters/features used to determine POS tags. For example, StanfordNLP pos tagger uses: "*(i) more extensive treatment of capitalization for unknown words; (ii) features for the disambiguation of the tense forms of verbs; (iii) features for disambiguating particles from prepositions and adverbs*" (read more [in the paper](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/papers/emnlp2000.pdf)). Features of OpenNLP are documented somewhere else which I currently don't know.

The models are probably trained on different corpora.

In general, it is really hard to tell which NLP tool performs better in term of quality. This is really dependent on your domain and you need to test your tools. See following papers for more information:

- [Is Part-Of-Tagging a Solved Task](http://www.stefan-evert.de/PUB/GiesbrechtEvert2009_Tagging.pdf)
- [Large Dataset for Keyphrases Extraction](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=6EC3587940FB74F681716E6BBA31EAD1?doi=10.1.1.330.1168&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

In order to address this problem practically, I'm developing a [Maven plugin and an annotation tool](https://git.noc.fh-aachen.de/marc.schreiber/Towards-Effective-NLP-Application-Development) to create domain-specific NLP models more effectively.

Comment: @H.Z. Is your question answered by my answer? I appreciate any feedback.